# JavaScript Regex split by hyphen and spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in the following format:
`90000 - 90000`
Where the numbers can be of a variable length, and then there is a space, hyphen, space between them. I'm trying to split this string into the two numbers with this Regex:

```
var regex = new RegExp('/([0-9])\w+');
```

But my array only contains one element: the original string which does not seem like it split.

Comment: Just use `input.split(/ *- */)`

Comment: We can give you the answer bit it's harder to *fix* your regex as it's unclear where it comes from.

Comment: @nicael Uh, I don't know much about Regex. Maybe instead of mocking me you could leave a helpful comment so I can try to learn. Thanks.

Comment: @TobyCaulk The answer was given in comment, it's trivial when you know regular expressions (and yes, it's harder when you don't). I don't mock you, I say we can't explain where you went wrong as we don't know why you thought your regex would help.

Comment: Oh, that's scary. [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: @DenysSéguret I wasn't replying to you, I was replying to. That expression came from here: http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `split` function:

```
var s = '90000 - 90000';
var a = s.split(/[ -]+/);
console.log(a);
```

Output:

```
["90000", "90000"]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your Regex statement.
First, if it is a regular expression it does not need to be enclosed in quotes. Second, you forgot the terminating `/` character.
Third, and most importantly, regular expressions are not needed here:

```
var string = "90000 - 90000";
var array  = string.split(" - ");
console.log(array);
```

outputs:

```
["90000", "90000"]
```

Comment: I understand they aren't needed, I was just trying to learn how to use them. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: Gotcha. In that case you could do what n-dru did, or this would work as well: `string.split(/ - /)`